# How do I use the ARM assembler in XCode?

Tags: ios, xcode, assembly, arm

Just for educational purposes, I would like to add a function to an existing iPhone app, written in ARM assembly. I don't need a tutorial on ARM assembly in general, because I already read too many of them. I just don't know how to actually run the code!

What I would like to do is something like:

useless.h:

```
void useless();
```

useless.s:

```
useless:
      bx lr
```

If this also works on the simulator it would be fine... On the simulator, the .s file would not compile, so I should maybe do something like:

useless.s:

```
#if I_AM_ARM
useless:
      bx lr
#endif
```

useless.c:

```
#if !I_AM_ARM
void useless()
{
}
#endif
```

I know the syntax I use is broken, but how do I write it correctly? (Breaking an app on the simulator just because I want to try some inline assembly is no option...)

The second-best option would be to use inline assembly, but I would strongly prefer non-inline assembly.

Thanks!

**Edit: I want to learn ARM assembly, so I would like to find a method to compile ARM assembly code, and to EXECUTE ARM assembly code.**

Comment: Declaring `void useless();` is correct. AFAIK the simulator compiles to native code rather than emulating ARM, so yes the asm won't work there.

Comment: If an optimizing compiler is used, `void useless() {}` will most likely compile into `bx lr` anyway.

Comment: @Notlikethat: You are right.

Comment: @tangrs: You are right, too.

Comment: But, hey guys... I want to execute ARM assembler code, because I want to learn ARM assembly. Shouldn't be so hard, right? I cannot learn ARM assembly if I don't have a compiler to build my code and if I don't have a platform to run the code.

Comment: An actual working example with a github link can be found at my blog post mentioned in the answer below.

Answer (score 4):

I finally found the answer myself. It's actually not that hard. I only solved it for the 32-bit ARM version though.

useless.h:

```
void useless();
```

useless.s:

```
#ifdef __arm__


    .syntax        unified
    .globl         _useless
    .align         2
    .code          16
    .thumb_func    _useless

_useless:
    //.cfi_startproc
    bx    lr
    //.cfi_endproc

// CFI means Call Frame Information
// Optionally. Use for better debug-ability.


#endif
```

useless.c:

```
#ifndef __arm__

void useless()
{
}

#endif
```

Notes:

The CLANG ARM Assembler syntax is a bit different from what you see in example all over the web. Comments start with `//` and `/* multiline comments */` are also supported. It also understands the standard C preprocessor. The function has to be defined as a Thumb function, if you specify an arm function (`.code 32`) the program will just crash. The line `.thumb_func  _useless` can be ommited and it works still. I have no Idea what it means. If you omit the `.code 16` line, the program crashes.

about the `#ifdef`. For ARMv7, `__arm__` is defined. For ARMv8, i.e. the 64bit-variant on the iPhone 5S, `__arm__` is not defined, but `__arm64__` is defined instead. The above code does not work for the 64bit-ARM-version. Instead, the implementation from `useless.c` will be used. (I didn't forget ARMv7s, I just don't have a device with that arch in my hands currently, so I cannot test.)

Comment: The use of .thumb_func to mark functions as thumb code IS NECESSARY for it to work properly (at least in Xcode 6).

Answer (score 3):

The simulator doesn't use arm. you'll have to write x86_64 assembly if you want it to run on the simulator. (probably).

Comment: I know. I want to write ARM assembler for the iPhone, and a plain C version for the Simulator. I just want to compile and execute any ARM code.

Comment: come on guys. is there really no one out there who has used ARM assembly on the iPhone??

Comment: are you looking for a precompiler flag that denotes arm64? If so you can use \_\_LP64\_\_

Answer (score 1):

The best way to learn is to take a look at actual working examples, see my blog post about [ARM iOS timing](http://www.modejong.com/blog/post10_arm_timing_framework/index.html). This example Xcode project shows how to mix ARM ASM and C impls of a function. There is also a very accurate timing module to run your code N times, because accurate timing is the hard part when it comes to optimizing the code.

Answer (score 1):

You can emulate ARM-Ubuntu with [QEmu](http://wiki.qemu.org/Main_Page) (there are some Windows ports of it, e.g. http://lassauge.free.fr/qemu/ ). If you are on Windows, you may need to emulate x86_64-Ubuntu in the middle. To create an ARM image you can follow the steps from this question: [Black screen in QEmu for ARM-Ubuntu (how to get GUI?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39043803/black-screen-in-qemu-for-arm-ubuntu-how-to-get-gui) (yes, unfortunately, you get no GUI with these steps, just a console to the ARM-Ubuntu machine, and you have to do the steps from Ubuntu). Then you can cross-compile your C++/C/Assembly programs from Windows/Ubuntu host to ARM-Ubuntu target.

```
clang++.exe -Wall test1.cpp -o test1exe -std=c++14 -Ipath-to-arm-linaro/arm-linux-gnueabihf/include/c++/5.3.1 -Ipath-to-arm-linaro/arm-linux-gnueabihf/include/c++/5.3.1/arm-linux-gnueabihf -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections --sysroot=path-to-arm-linaro/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc --target=arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf -Bpath-to-arm-linaro/arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/
```

For cross-compilation you would need to download and roll out a toolchain, e.g. `gcc-linaro-5.3-2016.02-i686-mingw32_arm-linux-gnueabihf.tar.xz` (Windows/MinGW) from https://releases.linaro.org/components/toolchain/binaries/latest-5/arm-linux-gnueabihf/ and replace "path-to-arm-linaro" in the above command with  the path to the toolchain.

Answer (score 0):

I just started working with iOS. The first thing I tried to do was add asm code to my project and ran into the same problem. The static data is handled slightly differently in 64-bit mode. I discovered how to do it by looking at the assembler output of the compiler. The same .S file will be compiled as both 32 and 64-bit in Xcode, so prepare it like this:

```
        .globl         _myfunction
        .align         2

        my_constant_data:
              .byte 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7

    #ifdef __arm__
        .thumb_func    _myfunction 
        .syntax        unified
        .code          16

    //
    // call from C as my myfunction()
    //
    _myfunction:
       ldr r0,=my_constant_data

    < write your thumb-2 code here >
       bx lr

    #else // or you can use #ifdef __arm64__
    //
    // Call from C as myfunction()
    //
    _myfunction:
       adrp x0, my_constant_data@PAGE
       add x0,x0, my_constant_data@PAGEOFF

    < write your Armv8 code here >
       ret

    #endif
```