# aabb frustum culling using NEON

Tags: ios, floating-point, arm, compiler-optimization, neon

i'm trying to optimize aabb box in frustum using NEON (ios, >arm7) and i'm just confused of benchmark results.

NEON version (GLKVector4DotProduct using NEON):

```
FORCE_INLINE bool box_in_view1(const GLKVector4& min, const GLKVector4& max)
{
#define test_plane(i) {                                                 \
    const GLKVector4& fp = frustum_plane[i];                            \
    if (GLKVector4DotProduct(fp, GLKVector4Make(min.x, min.y, min.z, 1.0f)) <= 0.0f && \
        GLKVector4DotProduct(fp, GLKVector4Make(max.x, min.y, min.z, 1.0f)) <= 0.0f && \
        GLKVector4DotProduct(fp, GLKVector4Make(min.x, max.y, min.z, 1.0f)) <= 0.0f && \
        GLKVector4DotProduct(fp, GLKVector4Make(max.x, max.y, min.z, 1.0f)) <= 0.0f && \
        GLKVector4DotProduct(fp, GLKVector4Make(min.x, min.y, max.z, 1.0f)) <= 0.0f && \
        GLKVector4DotProduct(fp, GLKVector4Make(max.x, min.y, max.z, 1.0f)) <= 0.0f && \
        GLKVector4DotProduct(fp, GLKVector4Make(min.x, max.y, max.z, 1.0f)) <= 0.0f && \
        GLKVector4DotProduct(fp, GLKVector4Make(max.x, max.y, max.z, 1.0f)) <= 0.0f) { \
      return false;                                                     \
    }                                                                   \
  }
  test_plane(0);
  test_plane(1);
  test_plane(2);
  test_plane(3);
  test_plane(4);
  test_plane(5);
  return true;
}
```

and without NEON:

```
FORCE_INLINE bool box_in_view2(const GLKVector4& min, const GLKVector4& max)
{
#define test_plane(i) {                                         \
    const GLKVector4& fp = frustum_plane[i];                    \
    float negw = -fp.w;                                         \
    if (fp.x * min.x + fp.y * min.y + fp.z * min.z <= negw &&   \
        fp.x * max.x + fp.y * min.y + fp.z * min.z <= negw &&   \
        fp.x * min.x + fp.y * max.y + fp.z * min.z <= negw &&   \
        fp.x * max.x + fp.y * max.y + fp.z * min.z <= negw &&   \
        fp.x * min.x + fp.y * min.y + fp.z * max.z <= negw &&   \
        fp.x * max.x + fp.y * min.y + fp.z * max.z <= negw &&   \
        fp.x * min.x + fp.y * max.y + fp.z * max.z <= negw &&   \
        fp.x * max.x + fp.y * max.y + fp.z * max.z <= negw) {   \
      return false;                                             \
    }                                                           \
  }
  test_plane(0);
  test_plane(1);
  test_plane(2);
  test_plane(3);
  test_plane(4);
  test_plane(5);
  return true;
}
```

in simple benchmark timings are:

```
box_in_view1: 1.9704s
box_in_view2: 0.0013s
```

it's 10 000 000 tests with static aabb box and static frustum (cube is inside so all tests returns true).

Tested on ipad3, ios7, compiler opt flags: -Ofast -ffast-math

I'm sure that GLKVector4DotProduct() really using NEON instrics in **ARM_NEON** path. Any explanation why is NEON results so much slower and why?

Comment: If you profile this with Instruments you'll probably find that you're spending most of your time in scalar code generated by `GLKVector4Make` constructing the NEON vectors, after which you're doing very little work with actual NEON instructions, so the overall SIMD benefit will be negative. Ideally your input vectors should already have 1.0 in the fourth element so that you can just load them directly.

Comment: You are doing terrible things to NEON. NEON doesn't like 'if's. With your codes, the CPU is wasting tons of cycles transfering data from NEON to ARM registers. I'll give you an example how to do this the way it's supposed to be done with NEON once I'm home.

Comment: @Jake'Alquimista'LEE i see. have you mentioned example please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is the FULLY OPTIMIZED version that must be much faster than your current one :

```
/*
    fanicBoxInView
    Copyright (C) 2014  Jake Lee

    This program is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify
    it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
    the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or
    (at your option) any later version.

    This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
    but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
    MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
    GNU General Public License for more details.

    You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
    along with this program.  If not, see <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.
*/

// int fanicBoxInView(void *pMin, void *pMax, void *pFp, unsigned int count);
// assert : count >= 4
    .text
    .arm
    .global fanicBoxInView

    pMin    .req    r0
    pMax    .req    r1
    pFp     .req    r2
    count   .req    r3

    .align 5
    .func
fanicBoxInView:
    vld1.32     {q12}, [pMin]
    vld1.32     {q13}, [pMax]
    subs    count, count, #4
    vmov.i32    q14, #0
    vmov.i32    q15, #0
    bxmi    lr
    vpush       {q6-q7}
    vzip.32     q12, q13

1:
    vld1.32     {q0,q1}, [pFp]!
    vld1.32     {q2,q3}, [pFp]!
    pld     [pFp, #64*3]
    subs    count, count, #4

    vdup.32     d20, d1[1]
    vdup.32     d21, d3[1]
    vdup.32     d22, d5[1]
    vdup.32     d23, d7[1]

    vmul.f32    d12, d25, d0[1]
    vmul.f32    d13, d25, d2[1]
    vmul.f32    d14, d25, d4[1]
    vmul.f32    d15, d25, d6[1]

    vneg.f32    q10, q10
    vneg.f32    q11, q11

    vmul.f32    d16, d26, d1[0]
    vmul.f32    d17, d26, d3[0]
    vmul.f32    d18, d26, d5[0]
    vmul.f32    d19, d26, d7[0]

    vmls.f32    d20, d24, d0[0]
    vmls.f32    d21, d24, d2[0]
    vmls.f32    d22, d24, d4[0]
    vmls.f32    d23, d24, d6[0]

    vrev64.32   q0, q6
    vrev64.32   q1, q7

    vadd.f32    q6, q6, q8
    vadd.f32    q7, q7, q9
    vadd.f32    q8, q8, q0
    vadd.f32    q9, q9, q1

    vrev64.32   q0, q6
    vrev64.32   q1, q7
    vrev64.32   q2, q8
    vrev64.32   q3, q9

    vcgt.f32    q6, q6, q10
    vcgt.f32    q7, q7, q11
    vcgt.f32    q8, q8, q10
    vcgt.f32    q9, q9, q11

    vcgt.f32    q0, q0, q10
    vcgt.f32    q1, q1, q11
    vcgt.f32    q2, q2, q10
    vcgt.f32    q3, q3, q11

    vorr        q6, q7, q6
    vorr        q8, q9, q8
    vorr        q0, q1, q0
    vorr        q2, q3, q2

    vorr        q14, q6, q14
    vorr        q15, q8, q15
    vorr        q14, q14, q0
    vorr        q15, q15, q2

    bpl     1b

    cmp     count, #-4
    add     pFp, pFp, count, lsl #2
    bgt     1b

    vorr        q14, q15, q14
    vpop        {q6-q7}
    vmov        r0, r1, d28
    vmov        r2, r3, d29
    orr     r0, r1, r0
    orr     r2, r3, r2
    orr     r0, r2, r0
    bx      lr

    .endfunc
    .end
```

The syntax above is for Linaro GCC. You'll have to do some changes for XCode: 
[How do I use the ARM assembler in XCode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21410485/how-do-i-use-the-arm-assembler-in-xcode)

Note that you have to assert (count >= 4);

Also note that the code runs most efficiently when (count % 4 == 0);

Have fun.

PS : I'm a professional optimizer with "optimization on demand" practices, and my clients weren't very pleased with my recent activities providing fully optimized codes here for free. Therefore, I was forced to make it GPL.