# Using inline assembler in iOS aarch64 application

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, assembly

I tried to compile some inline assembler for 64-bit iOS application.

Here's an example:

```
   int roundff(float _value) {
       int res;
       float temp;
       asm("vcvtr.s32.f32 %[temp], %[value] \n vmov %[res], %[temp]" : [res] "=r" (res), [temp] "=w" (temp) : [value] "w" (_value));
       return res;
   }
```

and I have this errors:

> Unrecognized instruction mnemonic.

But this code compiles fine:

```
__asm__ volatile(
                 "add %[result], %[b], %[a];"
                 : [result] "=r" (result)
                 : [a] "r" (a), [b] "r" (b), [c] "r" (c)
                 );
```

Than I founded that in aarch64 I have to use **fcvt** instead of **vcvt**. Because

```
int a = (int)(10.123);
```

compiles into

```
fcvtzs w8, s8
```

but I don't know how to write it in inline assembler. Something like this

```
int roundff(float _value)
{
    int res;
    asm("fcvtzs %[res], %[value]" : [res] "=r" (res) : [value] "w" (_value));
    return res;
}
```

also doesn't work and generates this errors:

> Instruction 'fcvtz' can not set flags, but 's' suffix specified.
>
> Invalid operand for instruction.

Also I need **round** instead of **trim**. (**fcvtns**)

Any help? Where I can read something more about arm(32/64) asm?

**UPDATE**
Ok. This: float res = nearbyintf(v) compiles into nice instruction frinti s0 s0. But why my inline assembler does not work on iOS using clang compiler?

Comment: why are doing this ? what are you using assembly for ?

Comment: Because I need the fastest function for round(float). **fcvtns** is Floating-point convert to signed integer, rounding to nearest with ties to even.

Comment: Google turns up [this](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.dui0802b/index.html) from the arm.com website.  If you open up the "ARM Compiler armasm Reference Guide" entry in the content pane, you will see entries for 'general instructions,' 'floating points instructions,' etc.

Comment: Just as a suggestion, I'd avoid inline assembly like the plague when it comes to something like iOS.  It's just asking for trouble in the long run.

Comment: Have you tried writing C that uses multiple steps to achieve the exact result that the instruction does?  Then check that the compiler optimizes it to that instruction.

Comment: Useful timing code for iOS ASM work is here http://stackoverflow.com/a/33766419/763355

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how you do it:

```
-(int) roundff:(float)a {
    int y;
    __asm__("fcvtzs %w0, %s1\n\t" : "=r"(y) : "w"(a));
    return y;
}
```

Take care,

/A

Comment: That's my version:
{ int res; asm __volatile__("fcvtns %[res], %s[value]" :[res] "=r" (res) : [value] "w" (value)); return res; }

Comment: A real answer to the asked question, not an opinion. Was looking for the exact same question, I know all about risks, etc. I just want to see an example, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the rounding you want using standard `math.h` functions that inline to single ARM instructions.  Better yet, the compiler knows what they do, so may be able to optimize better by e.g. proving that the integer can't be negative, if that's the case.

Check [godbolt](http://goo.gl/ln5UVG) for the compiler output:

```
#include <math.h>

int truncate_f_to_int(float v)
{
  int res = v;  // standard C cast: truncate with fcvtzs on ARM64
  // AMD64: inlines to cvtTss2si rax, xmm0   // Note the extra T for truncate
  return res;
}

int round_f_away_from_zero(float v)
{
    int res = roundf(v);  // optimizes to fcvtas on ARM64
  // AMD64: AND/OR with two constants before converting with truncation
    return res;
}


//#define NOT_ON_GODBOLT
// godbolt has a broken setup and gets x86-64 inline asm for lrintf on ARM64

#if defined(NOT_ON_GODBOLT) || defined (__x86_64__) || defined(__i386__)
int round_f_to_even(float v)
{
  int res =  lrintf(v);  // should inline to a convert using the current rounding mode
  // AMD64: inlines to cvtss2si rax, xmm0
  // nearbyintf(v); // ARM64: calls the math library
  // rintf(v); // ARM64: calls the math library
  return res;
}
#endif
```

godbolt has a buggy install of headers for non-x86 architectures: they still uses x86 math headers, including inline asm.

Also, your `roundff` function with inline asm for `fcvtzs` compiled just fine on godbolt with gcc 4.8.  Maybe you were trying to build for 32bit ARM?  But like I said, use the library function that does what you want, then check to make sure it inlines to nice ASM.

Comment: truncate_f_to_int compiles into:
fcvtzs w8, s0

round_f_away_from_zero compiles into:
frintx s1, s0
frinta s0, s0
fcvtzs w8, s0

But assember has only one instruction for this: **fcvtns**. I'm using clang for compilation with "Apple LLVM version 7.0.0 (clang-700.1.76)" and developing application only for arm64. (-Os)

Comment: Ok. this: float res = nearbyintf(v) compiles into nice instruction frinti s0 s0. But why my inline assembler does not work on iOS using clang compiler?

Comment: @Joker: IDK.  There was another question recently about inline asm for iOS apps, and speculation that Apple forbids it because they only compile to LLVM intermediate representation or something.  Apple maybe wants to be able to generate binaries for new CPUs as they become available, rather than having vendors produce final binaries directly.