# Black screen in QEmu for ARM-Ubuntu (how to get GUI?)

Tags: ubuntu, arm, qemu, xorg, xserver

I am hosting Ubuntu 16.04 on Virtual Box from Windows 10. Inside that Ubuntu 16.04, there is QEmu emulating ARM processor, running Ubuntu Trusty (14.04).

When I start QEmu as follows, it shows a window with title `QEMU`, but completely black client area:

```
qemu-system-arm -smp 2 --drive format=raw,if=sd,file=vexpress-8G.img -kernel vmlinuz-3.13.0-24-generic-lpae -initrd initrd.img-3.13.0-24-generic-lpae -M vexpress-a15 -serial stdio -m 2048 -append 'root=/dev/mmcblk0 rw mem=2048M raid=noautodetect rootwait console=ttyAMA0,38400n8 devtmpfs.mount=0' -dtb ./vexpress-v2p-ca15-tc1.dtb
```

The console of the guest OS (ARM-Ubuntu) works, boot messages are displayed in the same terminal where `qemu-system-arm` command has been run. But when I type `startx` command, it shows errors:

```
Loading extension GLX
(EE) 
Fatal server error:
(EE) no screens found(EE) 
(EE) 
Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support 
     at http://wiki.x.org
 for help. 
(EE) Please also check the log file at "/var/log/Xorg.0.log" for additional information.
(EE) 
(EE) Server terminated with error (1). Closing log file.
xinit: giving up
xinit: unable to connect to X server: Connection refused
xinit: server error
```

/var/log/Xorg.0.log contains the following:

```
[   214.406] 
X.Org X Server 1.15.1
Release Date: 2014-04-13
[   214.411] X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
[   214.411] Build Operating System: Linux 3.2.0-58-highbank armv7l Ubuntu
[   214.412] Current Operating System: Linux VM-Ubuntu1 3.13.0-24-generic-lpae #46-Ubuntu SMP Thu Apr 10 21:01:14 UTC 2014 armv7l
[   214.413] Kernel command line: root=/dev/mmcblk0 rw mem=2048M raid=noautodetect rootwait console=ttyAMA0,38400n8 devtmpfs.mount=0
[   214.416] Build Date: 16 April 2014  01:41:53PM
[   214.417] xorg-server 2:1.15.1-0ubuntu2 (For technical support please see http://www.ubuntu.com/support) 
[   214.418] Current version of pixman: 0.30.2
[   214.418]    Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
    to make sure that you have the latest version.
[   214.419] Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
    (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
    (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
[   214.431] (==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.0.log", Time: Fri Aug 19 16:21:42 2016
[   214.446] (==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
[   214.461] (==) No Layout section.  Using the first Screen section.
[   214.462] (==) No screen section available. Using defaults.
[   214.463] (**) |-->Screen "Default Screen Section" (0)
[   214.463] (**) |   |-->Monitor "<default monitor>"
[   214.468] (==) No monitor specified for screen "Default Screen Section".
    Using a default monitor configuration.
[   214.470] (==) Automatically adding devices
[   214.471] (==) Automatically enabling devices
[   214.471] (==) Automatically adding GPU devices
[   214.475] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/cyrillic" does not exist.
[   214.476]    Entry deleted from font path.
[   214.476] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/" does not exist.
[   214.477]    Entry deleted from font path.
[   214.478] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/" does not exist.
[   214.478]    Entry deleted from font path.
[   214.479] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi" does not exist.
[   214.479]    Entry deleted from font path.
[   214.480] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi" does not exist.
[   214.480]    Entry deleted from font path.
[   214.481] (==) FontPath set to:
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/misc,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1,
    built-ins
[   214.482] (==) ModulePath set to "/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/xorg/extra-modules,/usr/lib/xorg/extra-modules,/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
[   214.484] (II) The server relies on udev to provide the list of input devices.
    If no devices become available, reconfigure udev or disable AutoAddDevices.
[   214.485] (II) Loader magic: 0xb7008f18
[   214.486] (II) Module ABI versions:
[   214.486]    X.Org ANSI C Emulation: 0.4
[   214.487]    X.Org Video Driver: 15.0
[   214.487]    X.Org XInput driver : 20.0
[   214.489]    X.Org Server Extension : 8.0
[   214.495] Initializing built-in extension Generic Event Extension
[   214.496] Initializing built-in extension SHAPE
[   214.497] Initializing built-in extension MIT-SHM
[   214.497] Initializing built-in extension XInputExtension
[   214.498] Initializing built-in extension XTEST
[   214.498] Initializing built-in extension BIG-REQUESTS
[   214.499] Initializing built-in extension SYNC
[   214.500] Initializing built-in extension XKEYBOARD
[   214.500] Initializing built-in extension XC-MISC
[   214.501] Initializing built-in extension SECURITY
[   214.501] Initializing built-in extension XINERAMA
[   214.503] Initializing built-in extension XFIXES
[   214.503] Initializing built-in extension RENDER
[   214.504] Initializing built-in extension RANDR
[   214.505] Initializing built-in extension COMPOSITE
[   214.505] Initializing built-in extension DAMAGE
[   214.506] Initializing built-in extension MIT-SCREEN-SAVER
[   214.506] Initializing built-in extension DOUBLE-BUFFER
[   214.507] Initializing built-in extension RECORD
[   214.507] Initializing built-in extension DPMS
[   214.508] Initializing built-in extension Present
[   214.508] Initializing built-in extension DRI3
[   214.509] Initializing built-in extension X-Resource
[   214.509] Initializing built-in extension XVideo
[   214.510] Initializing built-in extension XVideo-MotionCompensation
[   214.512] Initializing built-in extension SELinux
[   214.513] Initializing built-in extension XFree86-VidModeExtension
[   214.514] Initializing built-in extension XFree86-DGA
[   214.514] Initializing built-in extension XFree86-DRI
[   214.515] Initializing built-in extension DRI2
[   214.516] (II) LoadModule: "glx"
[   214.537] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libglx.so
[   214.612] (II) Module glx: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[   214.613]    compiled for 1.15.1, module version = 1.0.0
[   214.614]    ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 8.0
[   214.615] (==) AIGLX enabled
[   214.616] Loading extension GLX
[   214.619] (==) Matched modesetting as autoconfigured driver 0
[   214.619] (==) Matched fbdev as autoconfigured driver 1
[   214.620] (==) Assigned the driver to the xf86ConfigLayout
[   214.621] (II) LoadModule: "modesetting"
[   214.625] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/modesetting_drv.so
[   214.628] (II) Module modesetting: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[   214.629]    compiled for 1.15.0, module version = 0.8.1
[   214.630]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[   214.630]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 15.0
[   214.631] (II) LoadModule: "fbdev"
[   214.635] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/fbdev_drv.so
[   214.638] (II) Module fbdev: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[   214.639]    compiled for 1.15.0, module version = 0.4.4
[   214.639]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[   214.640]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 15.0
[   214.642] (II) modesetting: Driver for Modesetting Kernel Drivers: kms
[   214.644] (II) FBDEV: driver for framebuffer: fbdev
[   214.647] (--) using VT number 7

[   214.652] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for modesetting
[   214.656] (EE) open /dev/dri/card0: No such file or directory
[   214.657] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for fbdev
[   214.658] (II) Loading sub module "fbdevhw"
[   214.658] (II) LoadModule: "fbdevhw"
[   214.663] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfbdevhw.so
[   214.666] (II) Module fbdevhw: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[   214.669]    compiled for 1.15.1, module version = 0.0.2
[   214.669]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 15.0
[   214.671] (EE) open /dev/fb0: No such file or directory
[   214.672] (EE) No devices detected.
[   214.674] (==) Matched modesetting as autoconfigured driver 0
[   214.674] (==) Matched fbdev as autoconfigured driver 1
[   214.675] (==) Assigned the driver to the xf86ConfigLayout
[   214.675] (II) LoadModule: "modesetting"
[   214.679] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/modesetting_drv.so
[   214.680] (II) Module modesetting: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[   214.681]    compiled for 1.15.0, module version = 0.8.1
[   214.681]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[   214.682]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 15.0
[   214.682] (II) UnloadModule: "modesetting"
[   214.683] (II) Unloading modesetting
[   214.685] (II) Failed to load module "modesetting" (already loaded, -1205831248)
[   214.686] (II) LoadModule: "fbdev"
[   214.689] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/fbdev_drv.so
[   214.690] (II) Module fbdev: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[   214.691]    compiled for 1.15.0, module version = 0.4.4
[   214.691]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[   214.692]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 15.0
[   214.692] (II) UnloadModule: "fbdev"
[   214.694] (II) Unloading fbdev
[   214.695] (II) Failed to load module "fbdev" (already loaded, -1205831248)
[   214.695] (II) modesetting: Driver for Modesetting Kernel Drivers: kms
[   214.696] (II) FBDEV: driver for framebuffer: fbdev
[   214.699] (++) using VT number 7

[   214.699] (WW) xf86OpenConsole: setpgid failed: Operation not permitted
[   214.700] (WW) xf86OpenConsole: setsid failed: Operation not permitted
[   214.701] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for modesetting
[   214.702] (EE) open /dev/dri/card0: No such file or directory
[   214.702] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for fbdev
[   214.703] (II) Loading sub module "fbdevhw"
[   214.703] (II) LoadModule: "fbdevhw"
[   214.708] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfbdevhw.so
[   214.708] (II) Module fbdevhw: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[   214.709]    compiled for 1.15.1, module version = 0.0.2
[   214.710]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 15.0
[   214.710] (EE) open /dev/fb0: No such file or directory
[   214.711] (EE) No devices detected.
[   214.711] (EE) 
Fatal server error:
[   214.714] (EE) no screens found(EE) 
[   214.716] (EE) 
Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support 
     at http://wiki.x.org
 for help. 
[   214.717] (EE) Please also check the log file at "/var/log/Xorg.0.log" for additional information.
[   214.718] (EE) 
[   214.723] (EE) Server terminated with error (1). Closing log file.
```

The complete steps it took me to create and boot an ARM-Ubuntu image are below (based on https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/Dev/QemuARMVexpress ):

```
# 1) setup the rootfs

sudo apt-get install qemu-user-static qemu-system-arm

mkdir vexpress
cd vexpress
mkdir qemu-img

# Create 8-GB image
dd if=/dev/zero of=./vexpress-8G.img bs=8M count=1024
sudo losetup -f ./vexpress-8G.img
sudo mkfs.ext4 /dev/loop0
sudo mount /dev/loop0 qemu-img

# Bootstrap Ubuntu Trusty armhf rootfs in the qemu-img directory
# For Ubuntu versions later than Trusty some commands fail
# For Ubuntu versions before Saucy there is no port to ARM
# Ubuntu Saucy is not supported anymore
sudo qemu-debootstrap --arch=armhf trusty qemu-img
sudo cp `which qemu-arm-static` qemu-img/usr/bin/

# setup serial console, apt repositories and network
sudo chroot qemu-img
sed 's/tty1/ttyAMA0/g' /etc/init/tty1.conf > /etc/init/ttyAMA0.conf
echo "deb  http://ports.ubuntu.com trusty main restricted multiverse universe" > /etc/apt/sources.list
apt-get update
echo -e "\nauto eth0\niface eth0 inet dhcp" >> /etc/network/interfaces

# root password
passwd


# 2) pick and install a kernel

# Fix locale problems http://askubuntu.com/questions/162391/how-do-i-fix-my-locale-issue
locale
sudo locale-gen "be_BY.UTF-8"
sudo locale-gen "en_US"
sudo locale-gen "en_US.UTF-8"
sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales

apt-get install wget ca-certificates
wget https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+files/linux-image-3.13.0-24-generic-lpae_3.13.0-24.46_armhf.deb
dpkg -i linux-image-3.13.0-24-generic-lpae_3.13.0-24.46_armhf.deb

# So far I'm getting the following warnings:
#   Warning: cannot read table of mounted file systems: No such file or directory
#   warning: failed to read mtab

# !!! press CTRL+D to exit the chroot
^D


# 3) Boot it up


# copy kernel, initrd and dtb files
sudo cp qemu-img/boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-24-generic-lpae .
sudo cp qemu-img/boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-24-generic-lpae .
sudo cp qemu-img/lib/firmware/3.13.0-24-generic-lpae/device-tree/vexpress-v2p-ca15-tc1.dtb .

# umount the rootfs img
sudo umount qemu-img

sudo chmod 777 vmlinuz-3.13.0-24-generic-lpae
sudo chmod 777 initrd.img-3.13.0-24-generic-lpae
sudo chmod 777 vexpress-v2p-ca15-tc1.dtb
sudo chmod 777 vexpress-8G.img

# http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/167165/how-to-pass-ctrl-c-in-qemu
# Allow Ctrl+C and Ctrl+Z on guest, changing them on host to Ctrl+] and Ctrl+[
stty intr ^]
stty susp ^j

qemu-system-arm -smp 2 --drive format=raw,if=sd,file=vexpress-8G.img -kernel vmlinuz-3.13.0-24-generic-lpae -initrd initrd.img-3.13.0-24-generic-lpae -M vexpress-a15 -serial stdio -m 2048 -append 'root=/dev/mmcblk0 rw mem=2048M raid=noautodetect rootwait console=ttyAMA0,38400n8 devtmpfs.mount=0' -dtb ./vexpress-v2p-ca15-tc1.dtb
```

I don't know if it's an Ubuntu (software) or QEmu (emulated hardware) problem.

Comment: If you want graphical output, pick a machine whose display hardware QEMU actually emulates, i.e. [not that one](http://git.qemu.org/?p=qemu.git;a=blob;f=hw/arm/vexpress.c;h=58760f40ca229d4da41b4ffe9dd8c7eb0a5c4e33;hb=HEAD#l389). This isn't a programming problem (unless perhaps you want to write an [HDLCD](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.dui0604e/CHDJGDHJ.html) model for QEMU...)

Comment: We do model the PL111 on that board though (but as you say not the HDLCD), so if you can persuade Linux to use the PL111 for graphics it should work. (This did use to work with older kernels, certainly -- I have vexpress-a15 images which boot with graphics on the PL111 display.)

Comment: @PeterMaydell, ok, but how to do this?